# Can I use Time as globally unique event version?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I found time as the best value as event version.

I can merge perfectly independent `events` of different `event sources` on different `servers` whenever needed without being worry about `read side` `event order synchronization`. I know which `event` (from `server` 1) had happened before the other (from `server` 2) without the need for `global sequential event id generator` which makes all read sides to depend on it.

As long as the time is a globally ever sequential event version , different teams in companies can act as distributed `event sources` or `event readers` And everyone can always relay on the `contract`.

The world's simplest notification from a `write side` to `subscribed read sides` followed by a query `pulling the recent changes` from the underlying `write side` can simplify everything.

Are there any side effects I'm not aware of ?

Comment: Clocks on different machines can drift apart. So you can't rely on time being the same everywhere.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: Is't any source of truth for time?

Comment: You can set up synchronization with atomic clocks, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: Here's the topic in google group :https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/WdTSsA0LwPs

Answer (score 2):

Time is indeed increasing and you get a deterministic number, however event versioning is not only serves the purpose of preventing conflicts. We always say that when we commit a new event to the event store, we send the new event version there as well and it *must* match the expected version on the event store side, which *must* be the previous version plus exactly *one*. If there will be a thousand or three millions of ticks between two events - I do not really care, this does not give me the information I need. And if I have missed one event on the go is critical to know. So I would *not* use anything else than incremental counter, with events versioned per aggregate/stream.

Comment: I don't mean to stop using incremental event versions per aggregate so I won't loose the ability of controlling the conflicts while a new event is adding to the stream.

Comment: What I'm trying to get is to be able to reorder different event's happened by different event sources in a right way when I'm reading them.So read side modules scale better.And I can distribute the write side development easier to be done by different teams.

Comment: If you use the EventStore (http://geteventstore.net) this is easy to do by projections and emitting link events, and subscriptions, if needed. I think somehow this approach can be applied to any type of event store, but projections are not easy.